# A Shell script to find and cd into a folder taking a folder name as argument in one step

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I tried writing a one liner in Bash,

```
find ~ -name Music -type d -exec cd '{}' \;
```

This one using find along with exec but I'm getting error:

find: `cd': No such file or directory

Second try with XARGS,

```
find ~ -name Music  -type d -print0 | xargs -0 cd
```

Now again i tried to write a script .sh

```
pathe=$(find ~ -name $1 -type d | head -n 1 )
cd $pathe
```

And tried to execute the script `./1.sh Music` ,and it didn't work.

Only thing that worked till now is by typing the below command directly into terminal

```
cd `find ~ -iname books -type d | head -n 1`
```

Can anyone help me out by pointing out my mistake ? I'm trying to write a one liner and to alias it later.

Note: The script didnt even work for find result with only one result and result without spaces.

I'm using konsole with bash version 4.2.45(2) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You must run `cd` in your current shell.** Running it in another shell won't work, as you've seen. Create a function. Example:

```
mycd (){
  cd "${1}foo"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried making a function mycd and it didn't work with xargs or exec. Please help me by providing me a one line for this using the mycd function.

Answer (score 2):

There were some problems with first 3 implementations:

1. `-exec` option expects an executable binary. cd is a shell builtin, not a binary, like /bin/bash
2. `xargs` also takes executable binary.
3. The code is correct. However, since you created a .sh file, & executed it, it got executed in a `subshell`. Thus, it created a subprocess (bash), found the directory, cd to that directory, & exited. Your current shell is un-affected.

There are 2 options to cd to the directory found:

1.Use subshell to change directory:

```
find ~ -name Music -type d -exec bash -c "cd '{}'; exec bash" \;
```

This starts a bash shell, & within that shell, it changes to the directory you want.
NOTE, that any changes you do will not be reflected in the parent shell.

2.Using bash function:

```
findAndCd(){
    pathe=$(find ~ -name $1 -type d | head -n 1 )
    cd $pathe
}

Usage:
findAndCd Music
```

Instead of `cd`, you may choose to use `pushd` instead. Personally, I don't like some command other than cd modifying my CWD & OLDCWD, without an easy way to restore both of them.

Comment: Thanks for explaining all this to me.Thanks a lot :)